# Button disappear by clicking on it to enable the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

When you click on the button, all checkbox inside the list element should get active. But by clicking on the button, the button disappears itself. 
What do I do wrong? 
Here is my code:

Here JavaScript:

```
$('.filter-arrow').click(function () {
        //get id from clicked element
        var id = $(this).attr("id");

        //switch class to display open arrow
        $(this).toggleClass("arrow-close");

        //get function to enable checkbox
        checkbox($('.parentcheck'), $(this))
});
function checkbox(check, arrow){
    if(arrow.attr("class","checkAll")){
        for( var i=0; i<check.length; i++){
            check[i].checked = true;
            var arrow_id = arrow.attr("id");
            arrow_id.toggleClass("uncheckAll");
        }
    }else{
        for(var i=0; i<check.length; i++){
            check[i].checked = false;
            var arrow_id = arrow.attr("id");
            arrow_id.toggleClass("checkAll");
        }   
    }
}
```

Here the HTML:

```
<ul>
     <li class="checkbox">
          <!--Button-->
          <div id="first-arrow" class="filter-arrow checkAll arrow-open"></div>
          <input id="check" class="parentcheck" name="parentcheck" type="checkbox"/>
          <p>first-element</p>
          <!-- begin sub content -->
          <ul>
              <li class="checkbox">
                  <div id="first-sub-arrow" class="arrow-open"></div>
                  <input class="input-checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
                  <p>first-sub-element</p>
                  <!-- begin subsub content -->
                  <ul>
                      <li class="checkbox ">
                         <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="subcheckbox" />
                         <p>first-sub-sub-element</p>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                         <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="subcheckbox" />
                         <p> first-sub-sub-element(2)</p>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
           …
     </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.filter-arrow{
    clear:both;
    float:right;
    height: 12px;
    width: 22px;
}    

.arrow-open{
        background:url(pic/arrow-close.png) no-repeat left top;
    }

    .arrow-close{
        background: url(pic/arrow-open.png) no-repeat left top;
    }
```

---

now its working... Im doing it without the class "checkAll" and "uncheckAll"
for now I wont do it with the click on the button - just with cklicking on the parent checkbox...

Just like this:

```
var filterGeschichte;

filterGeschichte = function( $filterContainer,$categoryToggler ){

    $categoryToggler.click(function(e){
        var $toggler = $(this);
        $toggler.nextAll("ul.filter-sub").eq(0).slideToggle(300).find("li").show();

    });
    $filterContainer.each(function(){
        $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
            var $that = $(this);

            //console.log( $that.is(":checked") )

            if( $that.parent().find("ul.filter-sub").length ) {
                $that.parent().find("ul.filter-sub").find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", $that.is(":checked") );
            }
        });
    });
};

// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){

filterGeschichte( $("#scrollthefilter form:eq(0)"), $("div.filter-arrow") )
```

Comment: Where is the button? Can't see it in the code

Comment: Please add a link to a jsfiddle test

Comment: Yes, seems to brought half of the code, Please check.

Comment: There is no element with the class "filter-arrow" which you attach your click handler function to in the sample html you provided. Also have you verified that the relevant css doesn't have some rule that hides your button?

Comment: please post your .arrow-close style..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking all checkboxes should be as easy as this:

```
$('.first-arrow').click(function () {
    $(":checkbox").attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Comment: Could you update your code to use my method instead? My three lines above does not hide the button...